# Vertex slide is creating a new vertex and not deleting the old one. How do I stop this?

Tags: modeling, vertices, geometry

In this screen cap you can see what happened. I slid the vertex using the vertex slide tool, but instead of moving the vertex, it just basically created a new one, and left the old one in place. I'm new to Blender, so if someone could tell me how to fix this, I'd be very happy.

[image]

Comment: Using the available information, you have double vertices at this location, most probably double faces too, it would help if you upload .blend file or provide more information about the process you're going through to do that.

Comment: Vertex slide doesn't create new vertex, you did, they were overlapping and you could not see them, and now that you moved one it revealed the other. Bottom line is you have duplicate geometry, so remove doubles to clean up your model.